# Grab the folders of different parent folderids and display output in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to grab all the folders under several parent folderids. I am using the code below but think it is missing something.

```
function searchFolders() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Search Folder');
  var range = [];
  range.push([ "FolderId", "Folder Name", "Owner", "Date Created", "URL" ]);

  var parentId = sheet1.getRange(2,1,sheet1.getLastRow(),sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues(); // list of parent folderids

  for (i=0; i<parentId.length; i++) {
    var parfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentId[i][0]).getFolders();  //retrieves the folders
    while(parfolder.hasNext()){
      var pchild = parfolder.next();

      var row = [];
      row.push(pchild.getId(),
               pchild.getName(),
               pchild.getOwner().getEmail(),
               pchild.getDateCreated(),
               pchild.getUrl())
      range.push(row);

      sheet1.getRange(i+2,2,range.length,range[0].length).setValues(range);
    }
  }
}
```

I was hoping for the code to grab the parent folderid then list the results in cols B-F.

parent folderid -- list the folders (Cols B-F), if it has 2 then 
grab the next parent folderid -- list the next folders in 4th row...etc. And if the folder is blank to write "none" then continue with the next parent folderid. I haven't added this scenario in my code (just thought about just now).

Currently, the results are as follows:
The headers are printed 3x in rows 2-4 (cols B-F) then it lists the folders in row 5.

[image]

Comment: In you script, the folders are retrieved from just under a folder. Does each folder have subfolders and do you want to retrieve all folders including all subfolders?

Comment: I am trying to understand how you're proceeding, why are you getting the IDs from  the sheet? Also, is your end goal to write all of the Ids for every folder in drive into the spreadsheet?

Comment: No subfolders. Only the folders listed under the parent folderid.

Comment: @ Alberto - I have all the parentids listed, I don't want all the subdirectories for each folders. I want to script to loop through by grabbing the parentId then grab the folders in it then go the next parentId then do the same. I want the output in the same sheet. I have a screenshot regarding this but I don't know how to post it here. 

ParenIds
- Folder1 (output in Column B) (Column C - Owner) (Column D- Date Created) Column E- URL)
- Folder2
ParentIds
- Folder1
- Folder2

Comment: To post a screenshot, you can update your question and do ![name](url), it would help seeing everything clearer. But to recap, you would be putting the child folder information in the same row, on the columns to the right of the parentID, correct? would you stay in the same row if there were more than one sub-folder?

Comment: @AlbertoMolina, I just added the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Your previous one was repeating the header lines because you were essentially writing the whole `row` variable every time, and it always had the header in it. I rewrote the function, now it organizes it as in your screenshot. Try the following code:

**UPDATED CODE**

```
function newSearch(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var i = ss.getLastRow() + 1; // Next empty cell in A
  var j = ss.getRange("B1:B").getValues(); // Same as i, but for columns B-F
  var bLast = j.filter(String).length + 1;

  var ids = ss.getRange("A2:A"+i).getValues(); // gets the list of folderIDs
  Logger.log(i + "     " + bLast);

  var currFolder;
  var children;
  var childFolders;
  var folderInfo;

  for (var x = 0; x < ids.length-1; x++){

    Logger.log("Length: " + ids.length);

    children = DriveApp.getFolderById(ids[x][0]);
    childFolders = children.getFolders(); //get the children of the main folders

    while(childFolders.hasNext()){
      currFolder = childFolders.next(); // subfolder information

      Logger.log(bLast);

      folderInfo = [[currFolder.getId(), currFolder.getName(), currFolder.getOwner().getEmail(), currFolder.getDateCreated(), currFolder.getUrl()]];
      ss.getRange("B" + bLast + ":F" + bLast).setValues(folderInfo);
      bLast++;
    }
  }
  ss.appendRow(["","//"]);
}
```

I put the `ss.appendRow(["//"])` command to create a separator between the executions of the code.

Comment: I tried your code but it was searching My Drive. My intent is Column A would be an "input entry" (not necessarily searching everything in My Drive folder) where I will populate it with different parentFolderIds then it would get the folders under the 1st parentFolderID and write it within the same row to right of it. I will continue to look into this, hopefully I'll be able to figure out.

Comment: @JMR please take a look at the updated code in the answer, I fixed to work on a sheet that has the header organized as you do (starting on A!) and then a list of the folder ids to read and check their sub-folders.